# Modifying a Specific Digit in DevExpress DateEdit while Masking Date as "d"

Tags: wpf, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui, devexpress-wpf

I'm working on a project that utilizes the DevExpress DateEdit control in a wpf application. The requirement is to allow users to modify a specific digit within the date while keeping the date masked in the format "d".

Currently, the DateEdit control has the mask set to "d", which works well for displaying and inputting dates. However, I need to implement a functionality that allows users to modify a specific digit in the date, for instance, 11/12/2013  to change only one digit in month to be 11 instead of to enter the two digits again [just select the digit and edit it].

```
<dxe:DateEdit x:Name="dtEndDate"
    Grid.Column="3"
    Height="50"
    Margin="5,0,5,0"
    Padding="10"
    dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="Office2019Colorful"
    Background="Transparent"
    BorderBrush="#2484BE"
    BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"
    FontFamily="Segoe UI"
    Mask="d"
    MaskType="DateTimeAdvancingCaret"
    MaskUseAsDisplayFormat="True"
    NullText="End Date" />
```